# Why i cannot find the Wordpress ACF custom field value not in database?

Tags: wordpress

**The problem**
I have a custom field of type "text" for my posts added with ACF (Advanced Custom Fields) plugin. I fill the field with a URL e.g "www.test.com" but I cannot find that value anywhere in the database.

**I tried**
1. I search for the value in all the tables using phpMyAdmin
2. I downloaded the .sql file, search it but still, I cannot find the value "www.test.com" anywhere.

**What I expected**
I was expecting the value to exist in the table "wp_postmeta". So I am not sure where or how that value is stored.

Any ideas how i can find and update the value via the database ? Thanks!

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. Please got through the link on how to ask effective questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you, i updated the question.

Comment: What is "ACL"? .

Comment: Hi brasofilo, i updated the question. Its ACF for Advanced Custom Fields plugin. Thanks for spottign this out!

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out what was wrong. phpMyAdmin didn't show the last table rows of "wp_postmeta".

So i reloaded the who phpMyAdmin web page and i finally was able to see the latest rows of "wp_postmeta". I found the values that i updated the fields with.

So for everybody that cannot see the values on the database, make sure you see the last version of the database.